# Como é que posso identificar se 2 HashMaps possuem Objetos com IDs em comum

Tags: java, android, expressões-lambda, hashmap

Neste momento estou a fazer um jogo de Cartas, no qual cada Jogador tem um inventário com as suas Cartas.

Estou agora a tentar criar um Deck e o meu objetivo fazer com que as Cartas que já se encontram no Deck não apareçam do lado do inventário para isso tentei utilizar o seguinte e código:

```
for (HashMap<String, String> cartaInventario : listaCartasInventario) {
                for (HashMap<String, String> cartaDeckInventario : listaCartasDeckInventario) {
                    if(cartaInventario.get(Config.TAG_ID_CARTA_INVENTARIO) != cartaDeckInventario.get(Config.TAG_ID_CARTA_DECKINVENTARIO))
                    {
                        cartasInventario.add(cartaInventario.get(Config.TAG_ID_CARTA_INVENTARIO));
                    }
                }
            }
```

Este código ainda não funciona, a minha questão é se existe alguma outra maneira mais eficaz de o fazer esta verificação como por exemplo utilizar lambda expressions.

Comment: Olá, poste o código na pergunta e não um print. Existe uma opção para inserir o código.

Comment: Peço desculpa, erro meu

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido.

```
for (HashMap<String, String> cartaInventario : listaCartasInventario) {
        cartasInventario.add(cartaInventario.get(Config.TAG_ID_CARTA_INVENTARIO));
        for (HashMap<String, String> cartaDeckInventario : listaCartasDeckInventario) {
            if (cartaInventario.get(Config.TAG_ID_CARTA_INVENTARIO)
                    .equals(cartaDeckInventario.get(Config.TAG_ID_CARTA_DECKINVENTARIO))) {
                cartasInventario.remove(cartaInventario.get(Config.TAG_ID_CARTA_INVENTARIO));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```